# What do “a bare foot” and “flat on his belly” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, collocation

In the opening prologue to the novel *A Game of Thrones*, two sentences left me with questions:

> The great sentinel was right there ať the top of the ridge, where Will had known it would be, its lowest branches a **bare** foot off the ground.

What does *bare* mean in that sentence above?

> Will slid in underneath, **flat on his belly** in the snow and the mud, and looked down on the empty clearing below.

And what does *flat on his belly* mean in that one?

Comment: There are many formatting devices in English orthography, and in the software here, by which you may make your questions more intelligible to readers. I have edited this question with some examples; please take note of them, and do your answerers the courtesy of following them in future.

Answer (score 2):

*Bare* in that sentence means “without anything else”. A *bare foot* implies that it is describing the distance as no more than a foot.

Essentially, the author is saying that the branches are very low to the ground. Because the branches are very low to the ground, Will has to lie down to crawl under them. *Flat on his belly* means that Will is lying on his stomach, flat on the ground. He must crawl on his stomach to get under the branches because they are only a foot off the ground.

Comment: Yes, *a bare foot* means the same as *barely a foot*. No, *bare* does not mean the same as *barely*, here or elsewhere.

Comment: You're correct, my answer was poorly worded. I'll rephrase.

Comment: i appreciate youur aid, cheers - btw çan i see cheers as synonym for saying thank you?

Comment: You can say _cheers_ for _thank you_ in many parts of the English speaking world (including mine, British). I don't know whether it is used everywhere.

Comment: The phrase is unfortunate, because _bare foot_ is a very common collocation (also as the adverb _barefoot_) but normally refers to a person's foot. That is not what is meant here, which is _foot_ the measure.